# Automapper Map All Members of Certain Destination Type

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm loading data from a third-party API where one of the objects contain a list of attributes that can be one of several values. For example:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "permissions": {
    "action_1": "allowed",
    "action_2": "not_allowed",
    "action_3": "allowed",
    "action_4": "not_allowed",
    "action_5": "limited",
    "action_6": "limited"
  }
}
```

The value for each permission can be `allowed`, `not_allowed`, or `limited`. My API response permissions model has these mapped to strings for simplicity, but I need to map these to an Enum when converting to my data model. I know I can map each property individually like so:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile {
  public MyProfile()
  {
    CreateMap<ApiResponsePermissions, Permissions>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Action1, o => o.MapFrom(s => MapPermission(s.Action1)))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Action2, o => o.MapFrom(s => MapPermission(s.Action2)))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Action3, o => o.MapFrom(s => MapPermission(s.Action3)))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Action4, o => o.MapFrom(s => MapPermission(s.Action4)))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Action5, o => o.MapFrom(s => MapPermission(s.Action5)))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Action6, o => o.MapFrom(s => MapPermission(s.Action6)));
  }

  static PermissionEnum MapPermission(string permission)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I also know I can use `ForAllMembers` to map every property, but can that be used to map specific properties based on the destination type? The actual destination class has other properties besides the permissions.

Relevant Classes:

```
public class Permissions {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

  public PermissionEnum Action1 { get; set; }
  public PermissionEnum Action2 { get; set; }
  public PermissionEnum Action3 { get; set; }
  public PermissionEnum Action4 { get; set; }
  public PermissionEnum Action5 { get; set; }
  public PermissionEnum Action6 { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponsePermissions {
  public string Action1 { get; set; }
  public string Action2 { get; set; }
  public string Action3 { get; set; }
  public string Action4 { get; set; }
  public string Action5 { get; set; }
  public string Action6 { get; set; }
}

public enum PermissionEnum {
  NotAllowed,
  Allowed,
  Limited
}
```

Comment: Can you post the of the `ApiResponsePermissions` and `Permissions` classes?

Comment: String to enum mapping is built in, as long as the names match.

Comment: And if they don't match, you can use `EnumMemberAttribute`.

Comment: `EnumMemberAttribute` works for me! But I'll leave this open in case this becomes relevant to someone else in the future.

Comment: @FelipeOriani I edited the question with the classes